# ./runtests (in django) ImportError: cannot import name 'NullTimeKeeper'

Tags: python, django

The following command was executed in the tests directory inside the development version of django

```
./runtests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runtests.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.test.utils import NullTimeKeeper, TimeKeeper, get_runner
ImportError: cannot import name 'NullTimeKeeper'
```

I am using python 3.8 and am following the instructions for contributing to django from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/contributing/ where I have resolved all errors up to this point. Could someone explain what I would have to do as I already ran

```
python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements/py3.txt
```

in my virtual environment that I created using

```
python3.8 -m venv /path/to/venv
```

Comment: Did you run this inside the activated venv? These commands need to be run in the same terminal in this order: `python -m venv ...` then `source venv/bin/activate` then `pip install ...` then `./runtests.py`. The packages need to installed into the activated venv.

Comment: Yes in that order and in the virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found the answer. It is solved by configuring python3 to 3.8 version instead of 3.6 in the following link [configuring python](https://dev.to/serhatteker/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-5hab) and then executing all of this in the virtual environment.